# How can I 'check' the "custom fields" box from the Screen Options?

Tags: custom-field, metabox, screen-options

I am using the latest version of WordPress v5.3.2. I am trying to find out a way [through Code] to enable 'Custom Fields' by default, when on the Add/Edit Post/Page pages, at least for the one's already having some values added to the associated Custom Fields.
I am using a different template file, for such pages/posts. Any help in this regard will highly be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: you have also to define what you want to do when user choice to hide the custom fields meta box or another meta box. [look here to see how it's handled in code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3.2/src/wp-admin/includes/screen.php#L142)

Comment: I just want to get it to be enabled at the time of activation of the theme - a child theme of T20 OR whenever user tries to open a custom post/page tied with some custom field.